# Where can I find Master-level Earth spells?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

I'm looking for master-level Earth spells. My shaman's got his Earth magic skill level to Master but hasn't found anyone willing to sell him the Master level spells. In particular, I'd like to find Acid Splash. Seahaven seems to have a lot of other master-level spells for sale, but not the Earth ones. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got access to these spells when I reached Karthal. Acid Spray and Poison Cloud were both available in the Great Library of Karthal.